# How to create errors for OneToMany product extension using mapPropertyErrors in Shopware 6.4.20.1

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I maked for product extension OneToMany, an array, some fields of elements of which are required. I want to track errors of required fields in my module using ...mapPropertyErrors . How can I correctly fill ...mapPropertyErrors and is it possible in principle?

Has anyone done this? I don't have any ideas. P.S. everything works well, saves, displays, the only problem is getting errors.

My relations:
product.extensions.productDates => 
[0] => [
....
startDate
.....
],
[1] =>[
....
startDate
.....
],,
....
[n] =>[
....
startDate
.....
],

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your questions about code, i.e. debugging questions like these, are served by not only mentioning that you get an error, but also by providing the code itself, a [mre]. We are not clairvoyant, so we cannot help you to debug code you do not show us. Also showing what you have already tried to solve the problem is appreciated. [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: I don't have any errors. I need advice on how to correctly write ...mapPropertyErrors for one To Many relations. That's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your `EntityExtension` looks something like this:

```php
class SomeEntityExtension extends EntityExtension
{
    public function extendFields(FieldCollection $collection): void
    {
        $collection->add(
            new OneToManyAssociationField('customEntities', CustomEntityDefinition::class, 'some_entity_id', 'id')
        );
    }

    public function getDefinitionClass(): string
    {
        return SomeEntityDefinition::class;
    }
}
```

Let's say the association has the property name `customEntities`. You can then use `mapCollectionPropertyErrors` to map errors that occur within the collection of associated entities.

```js
const { mapPropertyErrors, mapCollectionPropertyErrors } = Component.getComponentHelper();

Component.register('my-component', {
    // ...

    computed: {
        ...mapCollectionPropertyErrors('customEntities', [
            'someField',
            'anotherField',
            'yetAnotherField',
        ]),

        customEntities() {
            return this.user.extensions?.customEntities;
        },
    },
});
```

Note that we use a computed property `customEntities` for the mapping to access the entities from the extensions. Further note that you have to map the individual properties of the associated entities.

Then when you catch an unsuccessful save request, check the mapped error property. The accessor for the error property will follow the template `{entityCollectionName}{property}Error`, written in camel case. Since we used a computed property as a shortcut to the extensions, it will be used as the collection name.

```js
onSave() {
    // Required for this to work: Set the property directly to the entity
    // in addition to the setting of `extensions`.
    // Workaround for error mapping of extensions:
    this.entity.customEntities = this.entity.extensions?.customEntities;

    return this.repository.save(this.entity, Shopware.Context.api).then(() => {
        // ...
    }).catch((exception) => {
        console.log(this.customEntitiesSomeFieldError);
        /*
        [
            {
                "_id": "457b6678a8354877805fbb4d51878936",
                "_code": "c1051bb4-d103-4f74-8988-acbcafc7fdc3",
                "_status": "400",
                "_detail": "This value should not be blank.",
                "selfLink": "custom_entity.1efc44e47de9482f9932a4a258063a5b.someField"
            }
        ]
         */
    });
}
```